# PHP Multi language script

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to program a multi language php script (english and korean). However, the problem is the the data that has been added from the admin. I've an approach to create the constants in the script as `phrases`, but there will be many data which will be added from the admin.

For example, the admin will add schools to the script and show it in the main page. I've a table for each language for the `constants`

```
school_id       school_name                                 school_description
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1               ELI             This school is good for students who are looking to develope thier acadmic skills
    2               ALI             This school is good for students who are looking to develope thier conversation skills
    3               ELI             이 학교는 그들의 대화 기술을 개발하고자하는 학생들에게 좋다
```

as you can see in my database these data in english, and I want to give the admin the ability to add these data also in `Korean`. In the user interface, the user will see the phrases for the constant variables depends in the user page.

My solution is to add a field in database if the admin want's to show this school in the korean section or the english section. However, I want to ask you here if there any standard solution to do an approach like this.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use "one-to-many" table relation:

```
table school [school_id, school_name, default_desc]
table school_property [school_id, desc, facilities, advantages, disadvantages, language]
```

this way you can use more than two languages (e.g Korean, English and Japanese)

Comment: but i have a lot of things like `description`. For example, facilities, advantages, disadvantages, and we don't need a third language.

Comment: I've edit my answers, basically, you can add more field in table_school_property. BTW (for normalization sake) I will make a table called facilities, advantages and disadvantages. But it is not a must, depend on your case